# Switching from prefork.c to mpm resulting in a white page

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am running a website on Centos 7 using httpd with a constant traffic of 1500 users. As the performance of prefork.c is not the best, we are trying to switch to a mpm module. Unfortunately, after loading the mpm module, when we access the website, it serves a white page without any error in files. The website uses PHP.

Do you have any idea?

```
LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
   StartServers            10
   MinSpareThreads         40
   MaxSpareThreads         200
   ServerLimit             15000
   MaxClients              15000
   ThreadsPerChild         25
   ThreadLimit             64
   MaxRequestsPerChild     5000
</IfModule>
```